# Run a script when for loop is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

I have this JavaScript for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    $.get(arr[i]).done(function (html) {
        $(".main").append($(html).find(".section"));
        $('.section:not(:first) .blog-items-list').remove();
    });
}
```

When the for loop is ready. Then I want launch a other script / function. How can I do that? When I typing ,function. That is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "When the for loop is ready"?

Comment: Wouldn't you just enclose your code in a `function loop() {}` and call it when you need it?

Comment: "When i typing ,fuction. That is not working." ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var d = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    d.push($.get(arr[i]).done(function (html) {
        $(".main").append($(html).find(".section"));
        $('.section:not(:first) .blog-items-list').remove();
    }));
}

$.when.apply($, d).then(function() {
    // all get requests have finished
});
```

[`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) is a jQuery function that waits until all passed deferreds are resolved. As soon as it doesn't accept array of deferreds but multiple arguments instead - we use [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = arr.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    $.get(arr[i]).done(function (html) {
        $(".main").append($(html).find(".section"));
        $('.section:not(:first) .blog-items-list').remove();
        if(--count === 0)
            next();
    });
}

function next(){
    // after all done completed
}
```

Comment: I need to go to sleep not make silly comments :-) (+1 from me)